# next-i18next - Is it possible to change default language dynamically?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-i18next

I'm using next-i18next to handle internationalization of my next.js app.

Is it possible to change default language dynamically?
For example based on the top level domain?

```
const defaultLanguage = topLevelDomain === "de" : "de" ? "it";
```

EDIT: I'm also using localeSubpaths so that's why I'm trying to investigate the topic.

Comment: Sure it is. Initially you can assign any value you want and that can also depend on other things.

Comment: Thanks Johannes, I forgot to mention that I'm using localeSubpaths configuration. Is it possible to do it with this setup?

Comment: Sure, I mean the `localeSubpaths` is just a way to rewrite the locale part of the url based on a locale. This has little to do with setting the default language.

Answer (score 11):

For someone who use Nextjs `v10.0.0` up as written [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing), we have to use the newest [configurations](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next).

**`next-i18next.config.js`**

```js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'it',
    locales: ['it', 'de'],
  },
}
```

**`next.config.js`**

```js
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config')

module.exports = {
  i18n,
}
```

And to change the language we have to use `next/link` and `next/router`:

```js
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { Menu } from 'antd'
import { BorderOutlined, CheckSquareOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'

.
.
.

export default function YourComponent() {
  .
  .
  const router = useRouter()

  const selectedLang = lang => {
    return router.locale === lang ? <CheckSquareOutlined /> : <BorderOutlined />
  }

  return (
    .
    .
    .
    <Menu onClick={handleLangMenuClick}>
      <Menu.Item key="it" icon={selectedLang('it')}>
        <Link href={router.pathname} locale="it" >
          <a>Italian</a>
        </Link>
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="en" icon={selectedLang('de')}>
        <Link href={router.pathname} locale="de" >
          <a>German</a>
        </Link>
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
    .
    .
  )

.
.
}
```

But you have to bear in mind, that:

1. At **first render**, the default language will always refer to the `Accept- Language` header sent by the browser. In other words, the default language will be based on your target user's browser language settings.

   Let say that `Accept-Language` header sent by the browser is as follows (both `de` and `it` exists):

   ```
   Accept-Language: de, de;q=0.9, it;q=0.8, en;q=0.7, *;q=0.5

   # Note: the `q` value may be differs, the bigger will get the most priority
   ```

   then the default language will be `German`, ignoring the configuration `defaultLocale` at `next-i18next.config.js`.
2. If both `de` and `it` not listed in `Accept-Language` for example:

   ```
   Accept-Language: fr-CH, fr;q=0.9, en;q=0.8, cn;q=0.7, *;q=0.5
   ```

   then the default language will be `Italian` following the configuration we
   made.
3. For development purposes, we can change the browser language settings (I use
   google chrome) at `chrome://settings/?search=language` and order the languages
   based on your preference.
4. We can set the default language for **the next render** by programmatically
   add `NEXT_LOCALE` cookies to the target user's browser, based on their
   selection. Example:

   ```js
   import cookie from 'react-cookies'
   .
   .
   .  

   export default function YourComponent() {
     .
     .

     setDefaultLang = (lang) => {
        cookie.save('NEXT_LOCALE', lang)
     }
     .
     .
     .
   }
   ```
5. Always check the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs) to get the newest update.

Comment: How can we force the locale for the first render, where we do not have any cookie set ??? Question here https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/pooyhh/how_to_force_the_default_initial_locale_served_by/ . I see no way to intercept in next backend this logic without overriding server.js which is not good practice

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you can change. You should disable **localeDetection** and it will work fine:

### next-i18next.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['ru', 'uz', 'en'],
    defaultLocale: 'ru',
    localeDetection: false,
  },
  localePath: path.resolve('./public/locales'),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Migration from next-i18next v7 to v8 is explain through this articles https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/1040

```js
var languages = [
  ['English', 'en'],
  ['French', 'fr']
]

export default function YourComponent() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleLocaleChange = (data)=>{
    router.replace(router.pathname, router.pathname, { locale: data })
  }
  return (
    <Menu onClick={handleLangMenuClick}>
      {languages.map((row, index) => (
      <Menu.Item key="en" onClick={(row[1]) =>handleLocaleChange(row[1])}>
          <a>{row[0]}</a>
      </Menu.Item>      
      )}

    </Menu>
   )
}
```

Comment: Nah, that's a wrong way. Better to use Link in case if it's possible